# Smooth Custom AS3 Movieclip repel function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, physics, movieclip

I wrote this repel function (below) for 2 movieclips and I call it from a timer instead of an enter_frame listener (speed), but it has the tendency to jerk and not be very smooth. How can I smooth the movements? I was thinking maybe adding some sort of padding or something, but idk...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanx :)

```
function repel(mover2, mover) {
    var xdiff:Number = mover2.x - mover.x;
    var ydiff:Number = mover2.y - mover.y;
    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(xdiff*xdiff + ydiff*ydiff);

    if (dist < (mover2.width/2 + mover.width/2)){
        var angle:Number = Math.atan2(ydiff, xdiff);

        if ((mover.x - Math.cos(angle)*10) - (mover.width/2) > minx && (mover.x - Math.cos(angle)*10) + (mover.width/2) < maxx) {
            mover.x -= (Math.cos(angle)*10)*1;
        }
        if ((mover.y - Math.sin(angle)*10) - (mover.height/2) > miny && (mover.y - Math.sin(angle)*10) + (mover.height/2) < maxy) {
            mover.y -= (Math.sin(angle)*10)*1;
        }
        if ((mover2.x - Math.cos(angle)*10) - (mover2.width/2) > minx && (mover2.x - Math.cos(angle)*10) + (mover2.width/2) < maxx) {
            mover2.x += (Math.cos(angle)*10)*1;
        }
        if ((mover2.y - Math.sin(angle)*10) - (mover2.height/2) > miny && (mover2.y - Math.sin(angle)*10) + (mover2.height/2) < maxy) {
            mover2.y += (Math.sin(angle)*10)*1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of repelling effect you want to achieve, but you can base your code on a simple physic principle : the gravitational force between two mass. You can read more about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_force). Here's the formula (from wikipedia) :

```
F = G * (m1 * m2) / r²
```

F is the magnitude of the gravitational force between the two point masses,
G is the gravitational constant (about 9.81 m/s²),
m1 is the mass of the first point mass,
m2 is the mass of the second point mass, and
r is the distance between the two point masses.

You can simplify this if you don't want to account mass (i.e. both object have a mass of 1) :

```
F = G / r²
```

This is great, but as the definition says, F is only the magnitude of the force, i.e. you don't know the direction, only the amount. To get the direction, you'll need some vector :

F_12 = - G / r_12² * ru_12

Where :

F_12 is the vector of the force on object 2 due to object 1.
G is still the gravitationnal constant
r_12 is the distance between object 1 and object 2.
ru_12 is the unit vector from object 1 to object 2.

Check out [this site](http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/vectors/start.html) for a smooth introduction on vectors and liberate yourself from all this trigonometric stuff.

But note that the gravitationnal force is an attraction force. You can easily change this to a repulsion force by inverting its direction.

### Implementation

Alright, enough about theory. I've implemented a function which simulate this.

```
//make sure you set your initial conditions
obj2.vx = 0;
obj2.vy = 0;

function repel(obj1:MovieClip, obj2:MovieClip) {

    var G:Number = 100; // gravitationnal constant. You can play with this to get more or less force.
    var res:Number = 0.9; //a coeffient which reduce the speed when the object hits a wall.

    //this is a vector from obj1 pointing to obj2
    var distVector:Point = new Point();
    distVector.x = obj2.x - obj1.x;
    distVector.y = obj2.y - obj1.y;

    var distance:Number = Math.sqrt(distVector.x*distVector.x + distVector.y*distVector.y);
    //a unit vector is a vector of length 1
    var unit:Point = distVector.clone();
    unit.x /= distance;
    unit.y /= distance;

    //here's the actual formula
    var force:Point = new Point();
    force.x = G / (distance*distance) * unit.x;
    force.y = G / (distance*distance) * unit.y;

    //we don't have any mass, so a = F
    var ax:Number = force.x;
    var ay:Number = force.y;

    //simple integration
    obj2.vx += ax;
    obj2.vy += ay;

    obj2.x += obj2.vx;
    obj2.y += obj2.vy;

    // bounce to stage dimension
    if(obj2.x < 0){
        obj2.x = 0;
        obj2.vx = -res*obj2.vx;
    }

    if(obj2.x > stage.stageWidth){
        obj2.x = stage.stageWidth;
        obj2.vx = -res*obj2.vx;
    }

    if(obj2.y < 0){
        obj2.y = 0;
        obj2.vy = -res*obj2.vy;
    }

    if(obj2.y > stage.stageHeight){
        obj2.y = stage.stageHeight;
        obj2.vy = -res*obj2.vy;
    }

}
```

To use it, call repel at a regular interval. Note that obj1 will not be affected by the simulation. In my prototype, obj1 follow the mouse.

Try it and tell me what you think.

On a side note, using the Timer class is not faster than listening to ENTER_FRAME in any way. See [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a61a52657a1274ff66899-8000.html) and its two related articles for a better understanding.

Comment: I know this is a very old post - but hoping to get some help/explanation!  I'm trying to integrate this function into a game I'm working on, but I can't quite make it work.  If you could explain how to make this function work with 2 pre-existing MovieClips (ball1 and ball2) I would be unbelievably grateful!  For bonus points and extreme bonus gratitude, if you could explain (or point out) how to set the power of the repulsion between the two objects (so that it can be controlled dynamically) that would be awesome.

Comment: More specifically, I'm also having trouble with 
'//make sure you set your initial conditions
obj2.vx = 0;
obj2.vy = 0;'
---No matter where I put this code or how I arrange it, I get errors...